# Many to one migrations fails on foreign key long

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 models:

```
public class Text
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Text> Texts { get; set; }
}
```

My model build on user is that

```
e.HasMany(o => o.Texts).WithOne().HasForeignKey(d => d.Id).IsRequired();
```

When I try to run:

> dotnet ef migrations add

I get this error:

> with foreign key properties {'Id' : long} cannot target the primary
>   key {'Id' : int} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal
>   key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this
>   relationship.

**UPDATE:**

It should be able for new models to have a collection of the table Texts like:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Text> Texts { get; set; }
}
```

....

```
e.HasMany(o => o.Texts).WithOne().HasForeignKey(d => d.Id).IsRequired();
```

Comment: One's `int`, the other is `long`

Comment: yes but how can I say that the key property type is an long

Comment: Had a near similar caase. For the sake of future references,,, [this link] (https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/48998620/entity-framework-core--fk-with-different-datatype-than-pk) helped. From the popular answer... `[Column(TypeName = "int")]
public long Id { get; set; }` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the EF context configuration, specifically in the `HasForeignKey()` you are supposed to specify *Which property on the `Text` model should be the foreign key that points to the `User` model?*

Since `User` model's primary key is an `int`, the foreign key pointing from `Text` to `User` should naturally also be an `int`.

I think the mistake you've made is that you are configuring the PK of `Text`to also be the FK for the relationship `Text` -> `User`. Try to change your `Text` model to :

```
public class Text
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Text{ get; set; }
   public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

And your configuration to:

```
e.HasMany(o => o.Texts).WithOne().HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId).IsRequired();
```

Comment: If I add a new Model : Customer which has the same, collection of  ICollection<Text>Texts. your answer won't work, isn't there a solution where i can cange the 'naturally ' behavior?

Comment: Can you elaborate how my answer wont work and what model did you add ? Maybe with some code as well ? It is not possible to change the natural behaviour because the foreign key is something that is supposed to uniquely identify a row in another table. If that row's identification (primary key) is an `int`, then the only data type you can use to identify that row is `int`, otherwise it wouldn't be possible to identify it.

Comment: I am still not sure what you are trying to achieve. The `Customer` model is identical to the `User` model. Besides that, you still haven't fixed the foreign key problem. If 1 `User` can have more than 1 `Text`, even if you had IDs of the same types, it wouldn't be possible to achieve this relationship without having an additional (`UserId`) property on `Text`.

Comment: oh now I understood okey thank you very much for the explaination!

Answer (score 11):

Had similar problem using EF Core but didn't want to include the (equivalent in my class) UserId on the dependent entity Text, just to make happy EF. Finally found that you can replace the primary key used in the relationship (UserId) 
using HasPrincipalKey()

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(t => t.Texts)
        .WithOne()
        .HasPrincipalKey(u => u.Text);
```

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, change your Model naming please,

```
public class Text
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }// add a foreign key that could point to User.Id
    public string Body { get; set; }//you cannot have a string property called "Text".
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Text> Texts { get; set; } = new HashSet<Text>();
}

builder.Entity<Text>(table =>
        {
            table.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            table.HasOne(x => x.User)
            .WithMany(x => x.Texts)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Id)//<<== here is core code to let foreign key userId point to User.Id.
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        });
```

the reason we have to figure out which key is referred is because of multiple primary keys. I saw it once in MSDN, but cannot find it back.

You can use shadow properties for foreign keys, it looks popular now.

```
public class Text
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Text> Texts { get; set; } = new HashSet<Text>();
}

builder.Entity<Text>(table =>
        {
            table.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            // Add the shadow property to the model
            table.Property<int>("UserId");

            table.HasOne(x => x.User)
            .WithMany(x => x.Texts)
            .HasForeignKey("UserId")//<<== Use shadow property
            .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Id)//<<==point to User.Id.
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply drop all the migrations or the migration that made that Id, drop the database (if it is small or has no data) and add a clean migration

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in one-to-one relationship. If you are facing the issue in one-one relationship. Then try this:

```
    public partial class document
    {
        public document()
        {
            groups = new group();
        }
         public int? group_id { get; set; }
         public virtual group groups { get; set; }
    }
    
    [Table("group")]
    public class group
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("group_id")]
        public int group_id { get; set; }

        
        [ForeignKey(nameof(group_id))]
        public virtual document document { get; set; }
    }
```

Each document has single group. So, we can consider these settings.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<group>().HasOne(a => a.document)
            .WithOne(y => y.groups).HasForeignKey<document>(b => b.group_id);
```